# How can I create a conditional WHERE clause in SQL Server that returns multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have the following SQL code for a SSRS report. I simplified the code because the original query is much longer.
There is a parameter @ARTICLE which a user can input. What I want to do is create a conditional WHERE statement. If a user enters an article number (@ARTICLE) the query should filter ID's from Table1 that match with ID's for which the entered article number (@ARTICLE) have a match with a 'detailcode' from another table. If there is no article number given, do not filter (or skip the whole WHERE statement)

With the code below I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

Logically it works perfectly fine without the CASE statement, so when only the subquery is used to check for matching ID's. However, I only want to return matching IDs if the @ARTICLE parameter has a value. If it is NULL or an empty string I want to return all IDs (or just skip the entire WHERE statement). How can I include a condition in the WHERE clause that allows multiple rows to return given the example below?

I feel like my approach is way to complicated, any help is much appreciated!

```
DECLARE @ARTICLE AS VARCHAR(50) = '1234567'

SELECT * FROM Table1
    
WHERE 
Table1.ID IN (

CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(@ARTICLE,'')<>'' THEN
    (
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    Table2
    WHERE   detailcode IN (@ARTICLE)
    )
    ELSE Table1.ID
    END
    )
```

Comment: Fyi *case* is an *expression*, it does not provide control-of-flow - it *returns* a single scalar value.

Comment: As error states, this query `SELECT  ID  FROM   Table2 WHERE   detailcode IN (@ARTICLE)` can return more than one  record. You can test changing it by `SELECT TOP 1 ....`

Comment: @James, it's a very odd suggestion to simply neglect a lot of table data.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, clearly your subquery, `SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE detailcode IN (@ARTICLE)` is returning more than one value. I'm not sure why you are using `IN` either as your clause is equivalent to `= @ARTICLE`.

Comment: That suggest is poor at best, @James . Telling the OP that they should get the subquery to return an arbitrary row could easily not result in the results they want, and would likely be far from consistent.

Comment: @jarlh, I didn't say this is the solution, I said just for testing purposes....

Comment: @Larnu, I said you can test. With test, I mean you can check that's the problem. If you replace that with a top 1 the problem must disapear, so you can understand the issue is with that query.

Comment: It'll definition disappear, because `TOP (1)` would cause **1** row to be returned, @James , but it's not a solution and it's a poor test and it guarantees success. The error is already telling the OP the subquery is the problem; it's written in plain text: *"Subquery returned more than 1 value."*

Comment: ok... I just wanted to highlight the problem is with that query, which return more than one record... if you want to check, replace it by top 1 and you will see there is no error... Just that. I haven´t answered the question, it was just a comment...

Comment: how about using `where exists (subquery)`  in stead of `where id in ()`

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you're overcomplicating it a bit - if you look at the `LIKE` operator you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @filter NVARCHAR(50) = '123456';

DECLARE @f NVARCHAR(100) = '%' + @filter + '%';

SELECT * 
FROM [Table1] AS [t1]
     INNER JOIN [Table2] AS [t2]
                ON [t2].[joinField] = [t1].[joinField]
                   AND [t2].[detailCode] LIKE @f;
```

Where `@filter` is a parameter to the stored procedure.

Or to account for `detailCode` being null:

```
DECLARE @filter NVARCHAR(50) = '123456';

DECLARE @f NVARCHAR(100) = '%' + @filter + '%';

IF @filter != NULL    
     SELECT * 
     FROM [Table1] AS [t1]
          INNER JOIN [Table2] AS [t2]
                     ON [t2].[joinField] = [t1].[joinField]
                        AND [t2].[detailCode] LIKE @f;
 ELSE
     SELECT * 
     FROM [Table1] AS [t1]
          INNER JOIN [Table2] AS [t2]
                     ON [t2].[joinField] = [t1].[joinField];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check wether `@ARTICLE` is `NULL` or if it is `NOT NULL` and your subquery is fulfilled, like so:

```
WHERE
    ISNULL(@ARTICLE, '') = ''
    OR
    (
        ISNULL(@ARTICLE, '') <> ''
        AND ID IN
            (
                SELECT ID FROM Table2
                    WHERE detailcode = @ARTICLE
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it entire different, with an exists for example.
So you return all rows when `@ARTICLE is null or ''` OR  `exists at least one row in table2 with this article`
The `OR` will have the effect that no filtering is done when the variable is null or ''

```
DECLARE @ARTICLE AS VARCHAR(50) = '1234567'

select t1.*
from   table1 t1
where  ( isnull(@ARTICLE, '') = ''
         or
         exists ( select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.detailcode = @ARTICLE )
       )
```